# How to remove agents from population at a similar "Rate" that a Source block is creating agents

Tags: anylogic

I am creating a model where I require agents from a population to be removed at a certain rate after a certain moment in time. This rate should be similar and have the same variability as a "Rate" in a source block. My current method runs, but I would like to know whether this method is accurate and if there exists a more elegant solution.

To begin the removal, I set up a Timeout Event that creates a Dynamic Event.

```
create_dynamicEvent(exponential(rate));
```

My dynamic event then removes the agent by sending it through an enter block to a sink block, and sets up another instance of itself.

```
enter_sink.take(population.get(0));
create_dynamicEvent(exponential(rate));
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also use Dynamic Events. You may want to create the DE in the Source block, though, i.e. each created agent already "schedules" its destruction. May be more appropriate, but it depends on the real system.

Apart from that: all good